# Inverse from @XmlTransient

Tags: java, xml, annotations, jaxb

@XmlTransient prevents the mapping of a JavaBeans property to an XML representation. Is there something inverse from this, meaning that a method will be mapped even that not used by the WebService? If this is not possible, exists a workaround?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default all public fields and properties are mapped to XML with JAXB unless they are mapped with `@XmlTransient`.  If you only want explicitly annotated fields and properties mapped then you can mark the class with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)`.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/jaxb-and-unmapped-properties.html

Answer (score 0):

JPA's @Transient annotation prevents a serialized property from being persisted.